# ASP.NET MVC How to pass an id on dropdown list when using SelectList Query

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list with concatenated items to be used in a form . I have gotten the dropdown list to display those concatenated strings but I think it's failing to get an ID. (I'can't submit the form, dropdown blinks when I click submit), I take it this means no ID is being passed

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AdminCreate()
{

   var query = (from e in db.Employees
                     select e.FullName + "-" + e.EmployeeID + "-" + e.Site.SiteName);

   SelectList empList = new SelectList(query);

   ViewBag.empList = empList;

   return View();
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownListFor((model => model.Employee.EmployeeID), (SelectList)ViewBag.empList, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, you've to pass "Data" and "Text" in select list like this: SelectList empList = new SelectList(query, "DataValue", "TextValue");

Comment: @Conor8630, Use my updated answer! Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your query and `SelecList` as follows:

```
var employeeList = db.Employees.Select(e => new 
                         {
                            e.EmployeeID
                            FullName = e.FullName + "-" + e.EmployeeID + "-" + e.Site.SiteName
                         }).ToList()

SelectList empList = new SelectList(employeeList,"EmployeeID","FullName");
```

In your `@Html.DropDownListFor` replace `model.Employee.EmployeeID` with `model.EmployeeID` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.empList, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: It did seem to work but It does give me an error for a foreign key constraint which I'm unusre why its happeneing

Comment: Yeah, sure! The form is using two different tables! We can use TeamViewer

Comment: Yes! We can! /Give team viewer id and pass.

Comment: Can you start a chat, I don't have the privilege yet I don't think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188282/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-conor8630).